# Hardness of approximation for Disjoint Group Steiner Tree

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, combinatorics, approximation

Does anyone know any *constant factor* approximation hardness results on Group Steiner Tree when the groups partition the terminals, i.e. every terminal belongs to exactly one group?

The (intuitive) reduction from Set-Cover seems to fail in that case, and it also feels easier. It seems to me you could solve this if the underlying graph is a tree in polynomial time. Is this case still NP-hard to approximate within a constant factor for general graphs?

I've searched for partition/non overlapping/disjoint Group Steiner Tree etc. But I can't find anything, so I imagine this particular variant might have a specific name.

Group Steiner Tree is the following problem:

Instance: a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$, a collection of vertex sets (groups) $S_1,...,S_n \subseteq V$.
Find: a minimum-cost connected subgraph of $G$ that contains at least one vertex of every group $S_i$.

What I am interested in is the special case where there is some set $W \subseteq V$ such that $S_1 \bigcup \cdots \bigcup S_n = W$ and $S_i \bigcap S_j = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I understand it remains NP-hard, what I would like to know is if it remains NP-hard to approximate within some constant factor. As far as I understand the general case is NP-hard to approximate to within $\Omega(log^{2-\epsilon}(k))$ for $k$ groups in the general case.

Comment: I've edited the question. What I meant with hardness result was in the sense of constant factor, logarithmic/polylogarithmicly hard to approximate, not just NP-hardness to solve to optimality. Would you suggest another term that would have made the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the second paragraph of section 18.2 of these lecture notes, https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15854-f05/www/scribe/lec18.pdf, one can actually assume that the groups are pairwise disjoint wlog for any Group Steiner Tree instance. Suppose $v$ is a vertex  in $k \geq 2$ groups, $g_1, \ldots, g_k$. We can create $k$ dummy nodes, $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ attached to $v$ by edges of cost 0. Then set each dummy node $v_i$ to be in group $g_i$ and remove $v$ from all groups.